# Stroybook with Mui V5 - TypeError: can't access property "borderRadius", theme.shape is undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, storybook

Storybook docs shows this error.

> TypeError: can't access property "borderRadius", theme.shape is undefined.

I added the following into my theme to fix this but got the same error.

```
  shape: {
    borderRadius: 2,
  },
```

Also the theme colors are not working.
storybook-addon-material-ui theme dropdown is working fine. And the correct colors are listed in the **Material-UI tab**. But it's not applied in the **Canvas**.

canvas, theme colors not applied

[image]

error in storybook docs

[image]